# How to completely delete some specific database from realm-object-server

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I need to delete specific database from realm object server.

I tried to re-install realm object server, but it looks like its not touching existing databases. So after I reinstall I still see my realms. 
Dashboard currently not providing tools for administering.

So how do I remove realm?

Answer (score 4):

As you indicated, the Realm Object Server currently doesn't support the delete feature.

If you would like to start from scratch, the easiest way (and most failure-proof) is to uninstall the RPM/Deb package, then delete (or rename) the data directory (you can check what directory that is by looking at the configuration file in `/etc/realm/configuration.yml`), and then reinstall the package (which will recreate the data directory).

<del>I'll edit this answer when I get to the office with some specific commands. Can you tell me which distribution you are using in the meantime?</del>

Edit:

Depending on which version of the beta you're running, the data directory will be under `/var/realm` or `/var/lib/realm`. **I haven't tested the scripts below**, but it should give you a pretty good indication of what you can do.

### RHEL/CentOS

```
sudo service realm-object-server stop
sudo yum remove realm-object-server-de
[ -d /var/realm ] && sudo mv /var/realm /var/realm.backup
[ -d /var/lib/realm ] && sudo mv /var/lib/realm /var/lib/realm.backup
sudo yum install realm-object-server-de
sudo service realm-object-server start
```

### Ubuntu

```
sudo service realm-object-server stop
sudo apt-get remove realm-object-server-de
[ -d /var/realm ] && sudo mv /var/realm /var/realm.backup
[ -d /var/lib/realm ] && sudo mv /var/lib/realm /var/lib/realm.backup
sudo apt-get install realm-object-server-de
sudo service realm-object-server start
```

2nd edit:

Please be aware that there's an issue tracking this in our public issue tracker: https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues/13